# Can't override react-native's TextInput default padding

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following TextInput:

```
  _renderTextInput() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={TextInput => this.setState({TextInput})}
        style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: "maroon", paddingVertical: 0}}
        autoFocus={true}
        multiline={true}
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        returnKeyType="go"
      />
    )
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#E0E0E0", paddingVertical: 0}}>
        {this._renderTextInput()}
      </View>
    )
  }
```

What I am trying to achieve is a full-screen distraction-free zone for the user to type his post.

I know for sure that it's a padding issue but whatever I try I simply can not override it. I tried `padding:0` `paddingTop:0` `paddingVertical: 0` nothing seems to work...

Preview:

[image]

Comment: I tried your piece of code and it works correctly for me. Can you paste more of the surrounding code. There might be some style property in parent view that might be causing it

Comment: Have you tried margins instead of padding? Your flex container is causing this behavior. Also I think I need a bit more information on what you're trying to accomplish. How would you like the text field to appear?

Comment: @coderhacker I updated my question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After a long day of endless **g-o-o-g-l-i-n-g**, I found out what's causing the unwanted padding. It looks like by default, TextInput has the Text vertically centered hence why everything is exactly in the middle. To override it, just add:

`textAlignVertical: 'top'` to the TextInput's style and you're done. :)

@matt-aft 's comment about changing the style of the text helped to solve this.

Comment: there will still be extra paddings at the bottom, this is not a good solution

Answer (score 3):

Flex wont work here because you have other components also using flex so the screen is getting divided up. Using the device's height and width should work, or using a modal with a test input should also work.

```
const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');

style={{ height, width, backgroundColor: "maroon", paddingVertical: 0}}
```

Comment: It did not work. I tried your example and also removed flex from every view

Comment: The padding starts when the TextInput's height increase. I did a little bit of research and found out that the system adds a calculated padding by default.

Comment: what padding are you referring to? The top status bar? the navigation bar?

Comment: The TextInput. It's getting an inner padding top by default every time the height increases

Comment: ohh I see, misread your question..."What I am trying to achieve is a full-screen distraction-free zone for the user to type his post." that's what I thought you were trying to do. Yeah android might have that padding by default, try setting the text style height/width equal to the textinput height/width.

Comment: Where do I set the height/width of the Text?

Comment: sorry got that wrong, wrap the TextInput in a View and set those height/width the same

Comment: Padding vertical helped me. Thank you mate

Answer (score 0):

You just have to delete "flex: 1" because it makes your input place entire space.

Answer (score -2):

In case anyone is looking for a solution while using an Input, set it's multiline property to true.

multiline={true}